# What is the purpose of a metal strip mounted parallel to jointer/thicknesser blades?

Tags: jointer, thickness-planer

In my Proma HP-250/3-400 jointer-thicknesser, the following black sheet of metal is mounted parallel to the blade cylinder.

[image]

Do you have any idea what purpose does it serve?

[image]

[image]

It doesn't seem to be listed in the schematic (which doesn't have part descriptions anyway).

[image]

Comment: Is it in the path of ejected chips?

Comment: @Graphus Indeed, when the machine is in jointer mode, the sheet of metal seems to prevent the chips from flying away from the dust collector nozzle. This could be it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on location and how it's angled, this appears to be a deflector for chips. Why it's not a numbered part in the parts diagram is a mystery!